# Render text box with transparent background on top of image in React Native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to render a block with white text on top of an image in my testing of React Native. But instead i get a black block on top of my image with white text in it. Not what I had expected. How do you render a text block with transparent background?

**Current result**

[image]

**Render function**

```
render: function(){
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image 
        style={styles.backdrop} 
        source={{uri: 'https://unsplash.com/photos/JWiMShWiF14/download'}}>
          <Text style={styles.headline}>Headline</Text>
      </Image>
    </View>
  );
)
```

**Stylesheet function**

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    width: 320
  },
  backdrop: {
    paddingTop: 60,
    width: 320,
    height: 120
  },
  headline: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    color: 'white'
  }
});
```

Comment: Careful, this is now deprecated : 
" Using <Image> with children is deprecated and will be an error in the near future. Please reconsider the layout or use <ImageBackground> instead. "

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**PLEASE NOTE: This answer is now vastly out of date. This was applicable the day React Native was open sourced back in 2015. Today this way of doing this is deprecated.**

> "Using  with children is deprecated and will be an error in the
> near future. Please reconsider the layout or use 
> instead."

[See the docs https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#background-image-via-nesting](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#background-image-via-nesting)

---

---

---

You can accomplish this by adding a `View` inside the `Image` like so:

```
render: function(){
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image 
        style={styles.backdrop} 
        source={{uri: 'https://unsplash.com/photos/JWiMShWiF14/download'}}>
          <View style={styles.backdropView}>
            <Text style={styles.headline}>Headline</Text>
          </View>
      </Image>
    </View>
  );
)
```

**Stylesheet function**

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    width: 320
  },
  backdrop: {
    paddingTop: 60,
    width: 320,
    height: 120
  },
  backdropView: {
    height: 120,
    width: 320,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
  },
  headline: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    color: 'white'
  }
});
```

Comment: Typo, replaced welcome with headline, which was defined.

Comment: Work nice.
Thank you so much

Comment: Yes @blacksun but you can use [ImageBackground](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting) which I already used and works well

Comment: Trying this resulted in an error: The `<Image>` component cannot contain children.

Answer (score 8):

**backgroundColor: 'transparent'** 
This actually is a performance optimization and it is rather aggressive.

"*< Text >* elements inherit the background color of their parent *< View >* but this behavior causes more annoyance that helps in my opinion. A simple example is an *< Image >* with nested *< Text >*. The text nodes will take the background color or the parent views instead and will hide the image. Then we have to set **backgroundColor: 'transparent'** on the text nodes to fix it.

This behavior also doesn't happen on Android, the *< Text >* nodes always have a transparent background by default. This causes a few surprises when developing something on Android then testing it on iOS." - https://github.com/janicduplessis

This is from a discussion where users raised it as an issue. Read it more here - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7964

The easiest way like Colin said above is to set the **backgroundColor** of the container to **rgba(0,0,0,0)**

Answer (score 7):

Internally, I see that React Native does translate alpha values and the special case of `transparent` into the correct UIColor with alpha values, so that aspect of this is working and it's easy to validate this experimentally.

Notice that if you set the `backgroundColor` of your container to `transparent` (or `rgba(0,0,0,0)`), you also get a transparent text block - that knowledge should help you work around this problem. However I think it's possible to interpret this as a bug since that's not the behaviour one would expect, it feels like some kind of stacking problem.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem. Try removing `backgroundColor: '#000000',` from your container styles. Not sure why, but the background colour of the top-level component seems to be used in this case.