# React Native - How to display content over background Image and Vertically center that content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This same question is previously asked by many people. The issue is that
**Image component cannot contain children** .If you want to render content on top of an image, consider using the `<ImageBackground>` component or absolute positioning.

I have referred the article [Text Over Image](https://medium.com/@mheavers/vertically-centering-text-over-images-in-react-native-with-flexbox-935e822751f3)  and previous question on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300732/render-text-box-with-transparent-background-on-top-of-image-in-react-native-ios)  . Content over image is working using `<ImageBackground>` component. But how to make it work using `<Image>` component instead?

Answer (score 2):

**Part 1 (Text / Body of your question)**

To answer the text/body of your question, the [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html) say:

> A common feature request from developers familiar with the web is
>   background-image. To handle this use case, you can use the
>   `<ImageBackground>` component, which has the same props as , and
>   add whatever children to it you would like to layer on top of it.

Thus, `<ImageBackground>` component is specifically designed for ability to display content over a background image. So, you **must** use `<ImageBackground>` component for placing content over an image. This behavior **cannot** be achieved through `<Image>` component.

**Part 2 (Title of your question)**

Now, to answer the TITLE of your question, try this:

```
<ImageBackground
  style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}
  source={require('path/to/img')}>
     <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', width: '100%' }}>
         <Text>Centered Text (both vertically and horizontally)</Text>
     </View>
</ImageBackground>
```

`justifyContent` works along primary axis (in this case `column`/vertical). `alignItems` works along secondary axis (in this case `row`/horizontal).

You may not need `width: '100%'` in child View, but I think that I've experienced some issues a couple of times. So you can experiment with that.

Comment: Please also refer first part of my answer (official docs are also quoted there). `<ImageBackground>` component is specifically designed to give ability to place content over a background image. This behavior cannot be achieved through `<Image>` component.